# How do I override the OS X hostname that is assigned by DHCP?

Tags: mac-osx, hostname, osx-snow-leopard

I want to force OS X 10.6 to use the hostname that I assign it but still be able to use DHCP.

The old method of editinng `/etc/hostconfig` is not good anymore, the file containing `"This file is going ways"` message at the top.

How to do this?

Comment: Why is DHCP issuing a hostname?  If no good reason, switch it off at DHCP level.

Comment: LOL, I suppose you are working in a micro-environment :)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/49891/57219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem too, at my wife's school, where they have a DHCP server. She's running 10.6.6 Snow Leopard. Everytime I'd open Terminal on this network, the hostname would be set to something else.

I found a solution posted by user "Wolf" on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/50104).
If for some reason, the post is gone, here's what Wolf mentioned, that worked for me:

> Set it in the Terminal with
>   `sudo scutil --set HostName <putinyourhostname_or_fqdn_here>`
>   like in: `sudo scutil --set HostName server1.mynetwork.com`

Worked like a charm. I'm hoping when my wife takes her laptop home and returns on Monday I won't have to re-run this command. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it still works on Snow Leopard, but this used to work on Tiger at least:

In `/etc/hostconfig`:

```
#HOSTNAME=-AUTOMATIC-
HOSTNAME=your.host.name
```

(See http://www.geektimes.com/macintosh/os/x/10_0/core/hostname.html )

Comment: This answer is no longer valid for current OS X versions. See the answer here http://superuser.com/a/50104/57219 which works at least up to 10.8.3